# MaskMoney JQuery give wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form using this maskMoney Jquery PLugin
https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney

and it's giving a wrong value when there's only 1 number behind the decimal symbol
(Ex: If I want to write "300.50" it will show "30.05")

But when I try with 2 number behind decimal symbol, it show the correct value (ex : If I want to write "300.59", it show "300.59")

My code is only this

`$('#product_price_1').maskMoney('mask',300.50);`

Even with hardcoded value like above, it's still showing the false result ('30.05')

Any body have the same issue like this ?

Comment: This looks like something you're going to have to address the author of the maskmoney library with.

Comment: so it seems the problem on the plugin it self @Difster ? Anyway, I already make an issue report.. https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/issues/232

Comment: Unless someone else is very familiar with that library, you're likely to get the best answer from them. But you might want to make sure you look through their documentation really well to ensure you're doing everything correctly.

Comment: okay thank you @Difster . I hope somebody came up with solution with this issue :) because it's a big deal for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and I managed to solve a simple way, I hope it works for you.

```
let element =  document.getElementById('product_price_1');
let value = element.value;

value = parseFloat(valor.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
document.getElementById('product_price_1').value = value;
```